# Erlang: variable is unbound

Tags: erlang

Why is the following saying variable unbound?

```
9> {<<A:Length/binary, Rest/binary>>, Length} = {<<1,2,3,4,5>>, 3}.     
* 1: variable 'Length' is unbound
```

It's pretty clear that `Length` should be 3.

I am trying to have a function with similar pattern matching, ie.:

```
parse(<<Body:Length/binary, Rest/binary>>, Length) ->
```

But if fails with the same reason. How can I achieve the pattern matching I want?

---

What I am really trying to achieve is parse in incoming tcp stream packets as LTV(Length, Type, Value).

At some point after I parse the the Length and the Type, I want to ready only up to `Length` number of bytes as the value, as the rest will probably be for the next LTV.

So my `parse_value` function is like this:

```
parse_value(Value0, Left, Callback = {Module, Function},
       {length, Length, type, Type, value, Value1}) when byte_size(Value0) >= Left ->
    <<Value2:Left/binary, Rest/binary>> = Value0,
    Module:Function({length, Length, type, Type, value, lists:reverse([Value2 | Value1])}),
    if 
    Rest =:= <<>> ->
        {?MODULE, parse, {}};
    true ->
        parse(Rest, Callback, {})
    end;
parse_value(Value0, Left, _, {length, Length, type, Type, value, Value1}) ->
    {?MODULE, parse_value, Left - byte_size(Value0), {length, Length, type, Type, value, [Value0 | Value1]}}.
```

If I could do the pattern matching, I could break it up to something more pleasant to the eye.

Comment: Based on your edit, I recommend having a parse function with either a *universal length header* (pretty normal) or having a variable header *based on the connection type*. A "user client" connection might have a 2-byte length header, so you always send those to `parse_user/N` but a "camera connection" may always have a 4-byte header, so you send that to `parse_camera/N` (or set the socket option to `{packet, 2}` or `{packet, 4}` respectively via `inet:setopts/2`). Beyond (and there is a lot beyond that) chat would be a better place to discuss this. Erlang is ideal for what you're doing though.

Comment: Looking at your code, it looks like you're implementing a stream buffer *and also* dispatching over `MFA`. There are more intuitive ways to deal with this I can show you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rules for pattern matching are that if a variable X occurs in two subpatterns, as in {X, X}, or {X, [X]}, or similar, then they have to have the same value in both positions, but the matching of each subpattern is still done in the same input environment - bindings from one side do not carry over to the other. The equality check is conceptually done afterwards, as if you had matched on {X, X2} and added a guard X =:= X2. This means that your Length field in the tuple cannot be used as input to the binary pattern, not even if you make it the leftmost element.

However, *within* a binary pattern, variables bound in a field can be used in other fields following it, left-to-right. Therefore, the following works (using a leading 32-bit size field in the binary):

```
1> <<Length:32, A:Length/binary, Rest/binary>> = <<0,0,0,3,1,2,3,4,5>>.
<<0,0,0,3,1,2,3,4,5>>
2> A.
<<1,2,3>>
3> Rest.                                                               
<<4,5>>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've run into this before. There is some weirdness between what is happening inside binary syntax and what happens during unification (matching). I suspect that it is just that binary syntax and matching occur at different times in the VM somewhere (we don't know which `Length` is failing to get assigned -- maybe binary matching is always first in evaluation, so `Length` is still meaningless). I was once going to dig in and find out, but then I realized that *I never really needed to solve this problem* -- which might be why it was never "solved".

Fortunately, this won't stop you with whatever you are doing.

Unfortunately, we can't really help further unless you explain the context in which you think this kind of a match is a good idea (you are having an X-Y problem).

In binary parsing you can always force the situation to be one of the following:

- Have a fixed-sized header at the beginning of the binary message that tells you the next size element you need (and from there that can continue as a chain of associations endlessly)
- Inspect the binary once on entry to determine the size you are looking for, pull that one value, and then begin the real parsing task
- Have a set of fields, all of predetermined sizes that conform to some a binary schema standard
- Convert the binary to a list and iterate through it with any arbitrary amount of look-ahead and backtracking you might need

**Quick Solution**

Without knowing anything else about your general problem, a typical solution would look like:

```
parse(Length, Bin) ->
    <<Body:Length/binary, Rest/binary>> = Bin,
    ok = do_something(Body),
    do_other_stuff(Rest).
```

**But I smell something funky here.**

Having things like this in your code is *almost always* a sign that a more fundamental aspect of the code structure is not in agreement with the data that you are handling.

But deadlines.

Erlang is all about practical code that satisfies your goals in the real world. With that in mind, I suggest that you do something like the above for now, and then return to this problem domain and rethink it. Then refactor it. This will gain you three benefits:

1. Something will work right away.
2. You will later learn something fundamental about parsing in general.
3. Your code will almost certainly run faster if it fits your data better.

**Example**

Here is an example in the shell:

```
1> Parse =
1>     fun
1>         (Length, Bin) when Length =< byte_size(Bin) ->
1>             <<Body:Length/binary, Rest/binary>> = Bin,
1>             ok = io:format("Chopped off ~p bytes: ~p~n", [Length, Body]),
1>             Rest;
1>         (Length, Bin) ->
1>             ok = io:format("Binary shorter than ~p~n", [Length]),
1>             Bin
1>     end.
#Fun<erl_eval.12.87737649>
2> Parse(3, <<1,2,3,4,5>>).
Chopped off 3 bytes: <<1,2,3>>
<<4,5>>
3> Parse(8, <<1,2,3,4,5>>).
Binary shorter than 8
<<1,2,3,4,5>>
```

Note that this version is a little safer, in that we avoid a crash in the case that `Length` is longer than the binary. This is *yet another good reason* why maybe we can't do that match in the function head.

Comment: Thanks a lot again for the detailed answer! I have updated the question regarding why I needed. The code I ended up with is pretty similar to your suggestion, so I guess that's good enough?

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code:

```
{<<A:Length/binary, Rest/binary>>, _} = {_, Length} =  {<<1,2,3,4,5>>, 3}.
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is mentioned a bit in [EEP-52](http://erlang.org/eeps/eep-0052.html):

> Any variables used in the expression must have been previously bound, or become bound in the same binary pattern as the expression. That is, the following example is illegal:
>
> ```
> illegal_example2(N, <<X:N,T/binary>>) ->
>    {X,T}.
> ```

And explained a bit more in the following e-mail: http://erlang.org/pipermail/eeps/2020-January/000636.html

> Illegal. With one exception, matching is not done in a left-to-right
>   order, but all variables in the pattern will be bound at the same
>   time. That means that the variables must be bound before the match
>   starts. For maps, that means that the variables referenced in key
>   expressions must be bound before the case (or receive) that matches
>   the map. In a function head, all map keys must be literals.
>
> The exception to this general rule is that within a binary pattern,
>   the segments are matched from left to right, and a variable bound in a
>   previous segment can be used in the size expression for a segment
>   later in the binary pattern.

Also one of the members of OTP team mentioned that they made a prototype that can do that, but it was never finished http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2020-May/099538.html

> We actually tried to make your example legal. The transformation of
>   the code that we did was not to rewrite to guards, but to match
>   arguments or parts of argument in the right order so that variables
>   that input variables would be bound before being used. (We would do a
>   topological sort to find the correct order.) For your example, the
>   transformation would look similar to this:
>
> ```
> legal_example(Key, Map) ->
>  case Map of
>     #{Key := Value} -> Value;
>    _ -> error(function_clause, [Key, Map])
>  end.
> ```
>
> In the prototype implementation, the compiler could compile the
>   following example:
>
> ```
> convoluted(Ref,
>        #{ node(Ref) := NodeId, Loop := universal_answer},
>        [{NodeId, Size} | T],
>        <<Int:(Size*8+length(T)),Loop>>) when is_reference(Ref) ->
>     Int.
> ```
>
> Things started to fall apart when variables are repeated. Repeated
>   variables in patterns already have a meaning in Erlang (they should be
>   the same), so it become tricky to understand to distinguish between
>   variables being bound or variables being used a binary size or map
>   key. Here is an example that the prototype couldn't handle:
>
> ```
> foo(#{K := K}, K) -> ok.
> ```
>
> A human can see that it should be transformed similar to this:
>
> ```
> foo(Map, K) ->   case Map of
>     {K := V} when  K =:= V -> ok   end.
> ```
>
> Here are few other examples that should work but the prototype would
>   refuse to compile (often emitting an incomprehensible error message):
>
> ```
> bin2(<<Sz:8,X:Sz>>, <<Y:Sz>>) -> {X,Y}.
>
> repeated_vars(#{K := #{K := K}}, K) -> K.
>
> match_map_bs(#{K1 := {bin,<<Int:Sz>>}, K2 := <<Sz:8>>}, {K1,K2}) ->
> Int.
> ```
>
> Another problem was when example was correctly rejected, the error
>   message would be confusing.
>
> Because much more work would clearly be needed, we have shelved the
>   idea for now. Personally, I am not sure that the idea is sound in the
>   first place. But I am sure of one thing: the implementation would be
>   very complicated.

UPD: latest news from 2020-05-14